# Remote Desktop software that works with audio (Windows)

Tags: windows, windows-7, audio, remote-desktop

I've tried:

- Windows 7's built-in RDP / "Remote Desktop Connection" tool => **works with audio, but there are crackles/pops**, even with [this trick](https://superuser.com/questions/1102524/audio-over-rdp-choppy-even-on-a-gb-lan-connection-why) and [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20170523072004/https://www.jdhodges.com/blog/improve-audio-quality-rdc-rd).
- UltraVNC => no audio support
- TightVNC => no audio support
- RealVNC Enterprise => **very good audio support**, no lag / no crackle, high quality ; but not free

**Is there a "remote desktop" software for Windows that both:**

- has good audio support
- is open-source or freeware

?